# Leaflet + Mapbox: Using custom icons on mapbox markers?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Is it possible to use a custom icon using mapbox's [simplestyle spec](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-simplestyle/) ? Here's what I am trying to do:

```
var myPoint = L.geoJson(myCollection, {
    filter: function(feature,latlng){
        switch: (feature.properties.category){
            case 'Auto Manufacturers' : return true; break;
                return false; break;
        }
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
    L.extend(feature.properties, {
        'marker-color': '#009688',
        //this maki icon works but I need to use my own custom icon
        //'marker-symbol': 'car'
        'icon': {
            'iconUrl': 'images/carIcon.png'
        }
    });
    return L.mapbox.marker.style(feature,latlng);
   }
});
```

Unfortunately, using my custom icon like shown above does not work. It would be nice if I could also simply do `'marker-symbol': '/images/carIcon.png'`, as well, but that didn't work, either.

**My goal is to easily change the hex color code of a marker and add a custom png icon on top of that marker.**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234428/mapbox-custom-marker-icons-from-geojson-properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324752/adding-custom-icon-and-marker-data-together-using-mapbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499631/loading-geojson-markers-into-mapbox-setting-custom-icon-image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265496/icon-url-in-mapbox